# change localhost directory to domain name through /etc/hosts

Tags: dns, localhost, hosts

I was wondering whether anyone could please advise how I can point a domain to a directory within my localhost instead of the root of my localhost?

For example in my hosts file:

127.0.0.1 www.domain.com

- This works

127.0.0.1/directory/ www.domain.com

- This doesn't work? But is the directory that I need to view when going to that domain?

Or is there a better way to set up multiple sites within your localhost, as I am setting up each site within their own directory?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
  ServerName  domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/demo/public_html/domain1.com/public


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mydomainname.com.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mydomainname.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```